# How to Make My Web Server written in Golang to support HTTP/2 Server Push?

Tags: go, server, http2

My Web Server is Coded in Golang and supports HTTPS. I wish to leverage HTTP/2 Server Push features in the Web Server. The following Link explains how to convert HTTP Server to Support HTTP/2 :- 
https://www.ianlewis.org/en/http2-and-go
However, it is not clear how to implement the Server Push notifications in    Golang.
- How should I add the Server Push functionality ?
- How do I control, or manage, the documents and files to be Pushed ?

Comment: Not much info, but on topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37872924/high-level-client-for-golang-http2-server-push

Comment: note that "Push notifications" is not the same as "server push".
By the way my experience on Go running in Google AppEngine is I need to set http headers like the following to indicate what files to push:

link:</images/bg.jpg>; rel=preload; as=image,</analytics.js>; rel=preload; as=script

Comment: https://rakyll.org/http2push/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go 1.7 and older do not support HTTP/2 server push in the standard library. Support for server push will be added in the upcoming 1.8 release (see the [release notes](https://beta.golang.org/doc/go1.8#h2push), expected release is February).

With Go 1.8 you can use the new [http.Pusher](https://beta.golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Pusher) interface, which is implemented by net/http's default ResponseWriter. Pushers Push method returns ErrNotSupported, if server push is not supported (HTTP/1) or not allowed (the client has disabled server push).

Example:

```
package main                                                                              

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/pushed", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        io.WriteString(w, "hello server push")
    })

    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if pusher, ok := w.(http.Pusher); ok {
            if err := pusher.Push("/pushed", nil); err != nil {
                log.Println("push failed")
            }
        }

        io.WriteString(w, "hello world")
    })

    http.ListenAndServeTLS(":443", "server.crt", "server.key", nil)
}
```

If you want to use server push with Go 1.7 or older use can use the [golang.org/x/net/http2](https://golang.org/x/net/http2) and write the frames directly.

Comment: Go 1.8 is also due out in Feb.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in other answers, you can make use of Go 1.8 feature (cast the writer to `http.Pusher` and then use the `Push` method).

That comes with a caveat: you must be serving the HTTP2 traffic right from your server.

If you're behind a proxy like NGINX, this might not work. If you want to consider that scenario, you can make use of the `Link` header to advertise the URLs to be pushed.

```
// In the case of HTTP1.1 we make use of the `Link` header
// to indicate that the client (in our case, NGINX) should
// retrieve a certain URL.
//
// See more at https://www.w3.org/TR/preload/#server-push-http-2.
func handleIndex(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  var err error

  if *http2 {
    pusher, ok := w.(http.Pusher)
    if ok {
      must(pusher.Push("/image.svg", nil))
    }
  } else {
    // This ends up taking the effect of a server push
    // when interacting directly with NGINX.
    w.Header().Add("Link", 
      "</image.svg>; rel=preload; as=image")
  }

  w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "text/html")
  _, err = w.Write(assets.Index)
  must(err)
}
```

ps.: I wrote more about this here https://ops.tips/blog/nginx-http2-server-push/ if you're interested.

Comment: The link to your article is currently broken. Is there an updated link?